# Table Row Click - Two Destinations

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to make an entire table row clickable, including the whitespace.  I've seen ways to do this with JavaScript and a click handler on TR, or just by making each TD as display:block.

The wrinkle is I also want to have some text in the row that links somewhere else, but doesn't trigger the underlying link for the entire rest of the row.  Essentially, this special text will be like a "badge".

Something like this:

```
T = Text
B = Badge
W = Whitespace
```

A single cell in the row may look like this:

```
TTTTT BB WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
```

Clicking T and W would go to one link, this is the usual case.
But clicking on B would open up a different link in a new window, and would NOT open the original link in the main window.

Looking for pointers in the right direction, whether this can be done in pure HTML/CSS, or JavaScript, etc.  Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried anything? What do you mean about white space? Are they empty cell? Any example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use A elements for navigation, then if the row gets a click from one, ignore it.

```
<tr onclick="doSomething(event);">
  <td>
    <a href="…">TTTTT</a><a href="…">BB</a>WWWWWWWWW…


function doSomething(evt) {
  var tgt = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
  if (tgt && tgt.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'a' && tgt.href) {
    // don't do click action
    return;
  } 
  // do click action
}
```

Oh, and don't make TRs *display: block* since they are supposed to be *display: table-cell*.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the event's `target` FF/Chrome/Safari, or `srcElement` in IE property.  Even if you are listening to an event on a TR, you should see `event.target` as the thing actually clicked.  You could then look at the element (or its parents) to determine what action to take.  More details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.target

Comment: I like this answer too, but went with the one above.  Thanks to both!